# Chat API (Deprecated) - Look like someone can continue?

Tags: facebook, api, chat, deprecated

I have been user of https://www.wantedly.com

Look like API 1.0 with list friend and web chat is still working on that website. Is there exception (someones can continue using API 1.0) or www.wantedly.com implemented particular mechanism by themselves to simulate that feature?

Have a look on Video made on May 8th 2015: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2QVQwwSUH0

Answer (score 2):

1. Dialog Send is **not** XMPP
2. Apps are moving from 1.0 on a rollout process that may take weeks from the initial April 30th date.

So *no* moving forward no app will be able to use XMPP.